# NSdate is showing two days prior to current date while converting to ticks in iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, timestamp, ios12

I am converting current date to ticks per minute in iOS.But the converted date is showing as two days prior to the actual date.
Is there any updates happened in iOS 12 version?
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Make sure you have the correct timezone on simulator / device. The NSDate will pick the device/simulator timezone by default.

Comment: Everything is correct.i don't know why its showing 2 days prior,there is no timezone with these difference.

Comment: Can't you see it's impossible to see what's going on without your code?

Comment: Please improve your question adding the core you are using.

Comment: How can i convert current date into ticks ?Currently using let interval = self.timeIntervalSince(Date().customMediumDateTimeFormatterWithUtcTimeZone().date(from: "0001/01/01 00:00:00")!) which returns wrong number.

Comment: @Ananya Did you fin the cause of the issue? I am having a similar problem where iOS 12 is returning one day before the current date....